# INVALID: RHEL 7.9 not detecting CD drive, no /dev/sr0

Tags: rhel, mount, data-cd

I am trying to mount a CD on a RHEL 7.9 system. It is an internal drive and works fine. It opens, closes and you can here it spinning up.

When I put a CD into the drive and attempt to mount it, I do not see `/dev/sr0`.

When I run `sudo blkid` I do not see any information for a CD drive.

Could the drive be blocked somewhere on Red Hat? I have verified it is not disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Are you checking for `/dev/Sr0`? The filesystem is case-sensitive so the `s` would be lower-case, and whether it's actually `sr0` depends on a lot of stuff (but `sr0` is the most likely name). Have you tried watching (e.g. with `tail -f`) `/var/log/syslog` to see if a new device is added (and what name it gets) when you insert a cd?

Comment: I just capitalized Sr0 when i was typing this up, I have not tried tail on syslog yet.
A message just appeared in dmesg that says `sr0 logical block address out of range`

Comment: But why? It looks silly with a capital `s` in the middle of the sentence in a place where it doesn't belong. I don't think I've ever seen that message from a cd, and as I can't make sense of it, my first thought is that `sr0` must be something else on your system.

Comment: I found the issue, to stop CDs from automounting someone renamed sr0 to sr999. I renamed it and everything is good